# Save in Cache api response WORKBOX

Tags: service-worker, workbox, angular-service-worker

I would like to save some data that comes from an API in cache in case I lose the connection that data is shown

I have a list of Work Parts, so if I go offline I would like to continue seeing those parts, since when I enter the component again, it makes the call to the API and brings them again and since there is no connection, it leaves it in white here would be to bring them from cache

```js
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';
import {clientsClaim, skipWaiting} from 'workbox-core';
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {CacheFirst, NetworkFirst, NetworkOnly, StaleWhileRevalidate} from 'workbox-strategies';
import {CacheableResponsePlugin} from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import {BackgroundSyncPlugin} from 'workbox-background-sync';
import {Queue} from 'workbox-background-sync';


declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();

const queue = new Queue('cola');

const bgSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('api-cola', {
    onSync: async ({queue}) => {
    let entry;
    while ((entry = await queue.shiftRequest())) {
      try {
        let clone = entry.request.clone();
        await fetch(clone);
        console.error("Replay successful for request", entry.request);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Replay failed for request", entry.request, error);

        // Put the entry back in the queue and re-throw the error:
        await queue.unshiftRequest(entry);
        throw error;
      }
    }
    console.log("Replay complete!");
  }
});

registerRoute(
  /\/api\/.*\/*.php/,
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);

registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.origin === 'https://xxx.xxx.com' &&
              url.pathname.startsWith('/api/'),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'api-cache',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200, 404],
      })
    ]
  })
);

registerRoute(
  /assets\/images\/icons\/icon-.+\.png$/,
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'icons'
  })
);
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

When you go offline when you return the connection a sync is done and this works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify what's _not_ working? It's unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using runtime caching, which means the app or the user would have to make the calls to the api at some point before they are offline so that the resources are available in the cache. Maybe [warm strategy cache](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#warm_strategy_cache) would work for you, if you know the urls before hand.

I also noticed that you are caching responses even if they return with a 404 code, so those would also not be displayed correctly.